# delete item from torch.Tensor

Tags: lua, torch

I have the following code writtein in lua.

I'd like to get indices for N maximum scores from `scores` and their corresponding scores.

It looks like I will have to iteratively remove the current maximum value from `scores` and retrieve the maximum again, but can't find an appropriate way to do it.

```
nqs=dataset['question']:size(1);
scores=torch.Tensor(nqs,noutput);
qids=torch.LongTensor(nqs);
for i=1,nqs,batch_size do
    xlua.progress(i, nqs)
    r=math.min(i+batch_size-1,nqs);
    scores[{{i,r},{}}],qids[{{i,r}}]=forward(i,r);
--    print(scores)
end

tmp,pred=torch.max(scores,2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I did not misunderstand, since the code you show (especially the foor loop) does not really seem relevant to want you want to do. Anyway, here is how I'd do it.

```
 sr=scores:view(-1,scores:size(1)*scores:size(2))
 val,id=sr:sort()
 --val is a row vector with the values stored in increasing order
 --id will be the corresponding index in sr
 --now you can slice val and id from the end to find the N values you want, then you can recover the original index in the scores matrix simply with
 col=(index-1)%scores:size(2)+1
 row=math.ceil(index/scores:size(2))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: could you elaborate on the part " slice val and id from the end to find the N values"?

Comment: I meantsomthing like `val[{{1},{val:size(2)-N+1,val:size(2)}}]` and the same with `id`, since the `N` greatest elements are at the end of the sorted tensor.

Comment: Note that this does not adress the problem of duplicates (I mean if `scores` contains, *e.g.*, two times the maximum value of, say, `100`), but I assume it is not a problem since it was not mentioned in your question.

Comment: so if I were to print N best vals, would it be something like `vals=val[{{1},{val:size(2)-N+1,val:size(2)}}]` and `print(vals)`? sorry I have no clue as to lua's syntax

Comment: and in your code `col(index-1)%scores:size(2)+1`, I'm assuming the `index`is the value of the `id` retrieved from `val,id=sr:sort()`?

Comment: No problem. But this is not lua syntax, rather, a syntax defined by torch itself. Yes, `print(vals)` would print a `1*N` tensor that contains the `N` highest scores. You might find this tutorial on slicing useful: https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/tensors/slicing.lua

Comment: Also, `index` is one of the `N` values from `id`, which also is a `1*N` row vector, where the element `id[{{1},{i}}]` is the index of `val[{{1}},{i}}]` in `sr`.

Comment: I didn't really get to solve the problem, so I posted a new question here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398461/torch-lua-retrieving-n-best-subset-from-tensor