# torch / lua: retrieving n-best subset from Tensor

Tags: lua, torch

I have following code now, which stores the indices with the maximum score for each question in `pred`, and convert it to string.

I want to do the same for n-best indices for each question, not just single index with the maximum score, and convert them to string. I also want to display the score for each index (or each converted string).

So `scores` will have to be sorted, and `pred` will have to be multiple rows/columns instead of 1 x nqs. And corresponding `score` value for each entry in `pred` must be retrievable.

I am clueless as to lua/torch syntax, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
nqs=dataset['question']:size(1);
scores=torch.Tensor(nqs,noutput);
qids=torch.LongTensor(nqs);
for i=1,nqs,batch_size do
    xlua.progress(i, nqs)
    r=math.min(i+batch_size-1,nqs);
    scores[{{i,r},{}}],qids[{{i,r}}]=forward(i,r);
end

tmp,pred=torch.max(scores,2);

answer=json_file['ix_to_ans'][tostring(pred[{i,1}])]
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt, I demonstrate its behavior using a simple random `scores` tensor:

```
> scores=torch.floor(torch.rand(4,10)*100)
> =scores
 9   1  90  12  62   1  62  86  46  27
 7   4   7   4  71  99  33  48  98  63
 82   5  73  84  61  92  81  99  65   9
 33  93  64  77  36  68  89  44  19  25
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x10]
```

Now, since you want the `N` best indexes for each question (row), let's sort each row of the tensor:

```
> values,indexes=scores:sort(2)
```

Now, let's look at what the return tensors contain:

```
> =values
  1   1   9  12  27  46  62  62  86  90
  4   4   7   7  33  48  63  71  98  99
  5   9  61  65  73  81  82  84  92  99
  19  25  33  36  44  64  68  77  89  93
  [torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x10]

> =indexes
  2   6   1   4  10   9   5   7   8   3
  2   4   1   3   7   8  10   5   9   6
  2  10   5   9   3   7   1   4   6   8
  9  10   1   5   8   3   6   4   7   2
  [torch.LongTensor of size 4x10]
```

As you see, the `i-th` row of `values` is the sorted version (in increasing order) of the `i-th` row of `scores`, and each row in `indexes` gives you the corresponding indexes.

You can get the `N` best values/indexes for each question (*i.e.* row) with

```
> N_best_indexes=indexes[{{},{indexes:size(2)-N+1,indexes:size(2)}}]
> N_best_values=values[{{},{values:size(2)-N+1,values:size(2)}}]
```

Let's see their values for the given example, with `N=3`:

```
> return N_best_indexes
 7  8  3
 5  9  6
 4  6  8
 4  7  2
[torch.LongTensor of size 4x3]

> return N_best_values
 62  86  90
 71  98  99
 84  92  99
 77  89  93
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x3]
```

So, the `k-th` best value for question `j` is `N_best_values[{{j},{values:size(2)-k+1}]]`, and its corresponding index in the `scores` matrix is given by this `row, column` values:

```
row=j
column=N_best_indexes[{{j},indexes:size(2)-k+1}}].
```

For example, the first best value (`k=1`) for the second question is `99`, which lies at the `2nd` row and `6th` column in `scores`. And you can see that `values[{{2},values:size(2)}}]` is `99`, and that `indexes[{{2},{indexes:size(2)}}]` gives you `6`, which is the column index in the `scores` matrix.

Hope that I explained my solution well.